# how to set a value for one property for every record in an array

Tags: arrays, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs5, sencha-architect

I have an array with 1 or more records. for every record for ex: there is a property id. I want to set this name to a default value : 8. Please help me.
Array: [{id: 2, name: "x"},{id: 4, name : "y"}]
I tried this way

```
if (!Ext.isEmpty(detailLineItems) && (detailLineItems.length > 0)) {
canProcess = false;
Ext.Array.forEach(array, function (r) {
    if (r.id == 0 || Ext.isEmpty(r.id)) {
        canProcess = true;
       //how do I set this id
        r.id == 6;

    }
});
```

Comment: Use ```array#map```. Sort you right out

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get your point

Comment: Use ```.map``` instead of ```.forEach```. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not change the internal id of records, as this may break everything; the value in `record.id` is expected by the framework to be the same value as `record.get(record.idProperty)`. Instead, you should always use the setter method: `record.set("id", 8)`.

But what you are essentially searching for is the [`defaultValue` configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-defaultValue) on your model field:

```
fields:[{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'int',
    defaultValue: 8
}]
```

Please be advised that the field `id` gets a special handling in ExtJS, as long as the model's [`idProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#cfg-idProperty) defaults to `id`. A store can contain only one record with the same non-null value in the field defined by `idProperty`, so if you add them all to the same store you end up with only one of the records, and all other ones are deleted. So if you need multiple records with the same `id` in the store, you have to change the `idProperty` on the model to something else, e.g.

```
idProperty: 'someNonExistentProperty'
```

This then may cause issues with store `sync` operations. If you only try to set the `id` to a fixed value because your backend requires integer `id`, and the default id generated for new records by ExtJS is non-numeric (e.g. `ext-myModel-1`), you can check out [`identifier: 'negative'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.identifier.Negative.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered by Alexander but just to mention, your code statement **r.id == 6;** is using the equality operator rather than the assignment operator **r.id = 6;** :-)